# Variable of type Self in static context

Tags: swift

I have to modify an existing `static` method with return type `Self`.
I am using `Self` as it is required to work for subclasses of `A` as well. As the modification potentially needs a dispatch sync block to create the data for the returnee, I have to introduce a local variable of type `Self`.

Error:

> 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class;

```
class A {
    //...
}

class B:A {
    //...
}

extension A {
   static private func foo() -> Self {
        var myVar: Self? //Error: 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class;
        // Get data for myVar, potentially in a dispatch sync block on another queue
        guard let safeVar = myVar else {
        return someGarbagr
        }

        return myVar
    }
}
```

Intended usage:

```
func someFunctionSomewhere() {
    let instanceOfB = B.foo()
    // use instanceOfB
}
```

I have tried all I can think of already:

```
type(of:Self)
Self.Type
...
```

I would like to avoid modifying it to a generic method for several reasons. The main reason is that we would have to mention the type explicitly to make a generic version be able to refer the return type:

```
let instanceOfB: B = B.foo()
```

Comment: Where is `foo` located in? A class? Then just use the class name.

Comment: @Sweeper I added more information to the question. I am using `Self` to support subclasses as well (that is required).

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're planning on doing with `myVar`, could you give a slightly clearer example? Nonetheless, `Self` is currently a bit of a weird type; [you can (ab)use type inference](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/f8b077cd938c418d668cdeff81b6ed2d) to get a variable of type `Self?`. Though why not do something more like `let someData = queue.sync { ... }; return self.init(someData)`?